# How can I play Red Alert 2 on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2

What should I get (and where from) to play *RA2* on Linux?

Comment: This video shows it working with wine: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USbEmTzRzy4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). Wine allows you to run .exe files and consequently lets you run Window applications on Linux. While it's not guaranteed to work for RA2, it's very unlikely that you'd be able to get it to run on Linux using any thing if you can't get it to work with Wine.

On the [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=167) page, it is reported to have silver/gold status, which means, it will most probably run fairly well, if not flawlessly. Check out the comments in each.